# Arrays - why does something work with one item and not another even though they (to me) appear the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

This works:

```
<div className='card'>
      <div className='card-inner'>
        <div className='card-front'>
          <img src={item.images[0].url} alt='Park Image' />
        </div>
        <div className='card-back'>
          <h1>{item.fullName}</h1>
          <ul>
  

  <li>
          {item.description}
        </li>
        <li>
          
        </li>
        <li>
        
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href = {item.url}>Park Website</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However when I add {item.entranceFees[0].description}

```
<div className='card'>
      <div className='card-inner'>
        <div className='card-front'>
          <img src={item.images[0].url} alt='Park Image' />
        </div>
        <div className='card-back'>
          <h1>{item.fullName}</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>
              {item.description}
            </li>
            <li>
              
            </li>
            <li>
            {item.entranceFees[0].description}
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href = {item.url}>Park Website</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

it seems to break. Chrome tells me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined"
[chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deZAQ.png)

[api screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO2ch.png)

The thing that I'm really confused about is that item.images[0].url seems to work fine, I can pull the image from what is returned.

Could someone please explain this to me? Much obliged.

Comment: ‘item.entranceFees[0].description’ says you have an “item” object with an “entranceFees” property. Do you?  And “entranceFees[]” says it is an array. Is it?  And you are trying to get the first item in that array. Are there actually any items in the array?

Comment: Well, other than it's obvious `item.entranceFees` exists but is likely an empty array, there's not much else to go on from the screen caps. Please update your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example so that we may see what else may be going on with the response data processing. If possible, a ***running*** code sandbox would be exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined` means `item.entranceFees[0]` is `undefined`, i.e. `item.entranceFees` is an empty array or a function/object without a `0` property.

The good thing is that we can be sure `item.entranceFees` exists. So debug from there.

For example: `{(item.entranceFees[0] || {}).description || "Oops, no entrance fees."}`

Comment: A beer that the snapshot doesn't represent the actual content, and `entranceFees` is empty

Answer (score 0):

That's because `item.entranceFees[0]` is returning undefined. This is because the object you are receiving from the api contains a property called `item` but you are refering to that object as `item` too. So basically, you need to put this instead: `item.item.entranceFees[0]` or maybe destruct the item from your api response like:

```
const { item } = response;
```

Comment: But then why `item.description` works? The snapshot seems to tell they are two nested `item` object but I think that comes from the UI

Comment: The second snapshot shows an object like this : { item: ... } that means that first you must assign to a variable or constant and then cosume the item property like: myObject.item.entranceFees[0]

Comment: I tried a similar object within the browser console and this gives me some truth when expanding. The first line is just an abbreviation of the actual content, expanding shows the whole object